# How to get live stock data from the SIX Swiss Exchange?

Tags: json

Do anybody have any experience with retrieving live stock data for a specific stock from SIX Swiss Exchange? Preferably as JSON data since I am going to display it on a website.

There are quite a few charting tools out there, so displaying the data is not the main issue.

The data do not need to come from SIX directly, any source is fine as long as it is reliable and up to date.

Any input is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you contacted them?

If you want it live, you'll have to pay with SIX or Reuters/Bloomberg. It's commercially sensitive data so any free feeds will be 15 or 30 minute delay

I found this [myMarketpulse](http://www.six-swiss-exchange.com/services/mymarketpulse/) on their site.

Comment: Yes, I've mailed them, haven't received an answer yet though. I'll dig a bit deeper though. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 2):

SIX provides their data as JSON:

```
http://www.six-swiss-exchange.com/marketpulse/ajax/fqs-invchartdata.json?id=CH0024899483CHF1&type=1&line=id,1d,,246&dojo.preventCache=1227087752715
```

this gives you the latest UBS (id=CH0024899483CHF1) rates but it will be delayed at least 15 minutes.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that this API is gone :( Does anybody know if it is still possible to access it somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Alpha Vantage's Quote Endpoint supports a lot of Swiss tickers.

Documentation: https://www.alphavantage.co/documentation/

Use tickers such as `NESN.SWI`.

Example: https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=GLOBAL_QUOTE&symbol=NESN.SWI&apikey=YOURKEY

Unfortunately, the other endpoints don't work if you set `outputsize` to `full`.

Comment: it recognize this symbol maybe, but it will fail when you try to get actually useful data like this https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED&symbol=NESN.SWI&apikey=YOUR_KEY